# Entity Framework 6 Foreign Key Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've got it setup with a User

```
public class User{
     [Key]
     public int UserId {get;set;}

     public virtual ICollection<Sub_User> SubUser {get;set;}
     //Other
}
```

and then another type of user based off the main user.

```
public class Sub_User{
     [Key]
     public int Sub_User_ID {get;set;}

     int UserID {get;set;} //Foreign Key to User in DB
     public virtual User User {get;set;}
     //Other
}
```

I cannot get it to work correctly unless I have it setup like below.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Sub_Users)
            .WithRequired(e => e.User)
```

This works like this. But the issue I'm having is why do I need to have an **ICollection** of sub user? I've tried just making it like

```
     public virtual Sub_User SubUser {get;set;}
```

and then changing how it works in the modelbuilder, but it doesn't work correctly and I get errors.

The Main user should only have 1 Sub_User, so I find it odd that the only solution online and the only way I can get it to function correctly, is by using a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are a few options for achieving what you are looking for. Where `Sub_User` tie to valid/existing `User` and `User` has at most one `Sub_User`. Using the `[required]` annotation in option 3 seems the cleanest and doesn't require any Fluent API configuration.

**Option 1)**

Add a `[ForeignKey]` annotation to the `int UserId` property of `Sub_User`

```
public class User {
     [Key]
     public int UserId { get; set; }

     public virtual Sub_User SubUser { get; set; }
}

public class Sub_User{
     [Key]
     public int Sub_User_ID { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("User")]
     public int UserID { get; set; }

     public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

**Option 2)**

Fluent API (with `[ForeignKey]` and `UserId` removed):

```
public class User {
     [Key]
     public int UserId { get; set; }

     public virtual Sub_User SubUser { get; set; }
}

public class Sub_User{
     [Key]
     public int Sub_User_ID { get; set; }

     public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{   
    // Configure UserId as FK for Sub_User
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOptional(u => u.SubUser) 
                .WithRequired(su => su.User);
}
```

**Option 3)**

You could also, without Fluent API, try setting [required] data annotation on the `User User` property of `Sub_User` and removing the `int UserId` property and `[ForeignKey]` annotation:

```
public class Sub_User{
    [Key]
    public int Sub_User_ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**

I created a sample MVC 5 EF 6 project and using the [Required] tag, Code First generated the following tables from these classes:

C#

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Sub_User SubUser { get; set;}
}

public class Sub_User
{
    [Key]
    public int Sub_User_ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

}
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [UserId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sub_User] (
    [Sub_User_ID] INT            NOT NULL,
    [Name]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Sub_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Sub_User_ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Sub_User_dbo.User_Sub_User_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([Sub_User_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId]) );


GO CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Sub_User_ID]
    ON [dbo].[Sub_User]([Sub_User_ID] ASC);
```

I was able to save User elements with both a Sub_User and no Sub_User, as in `Sub_User SubUser` is optional for a `User` object:

```
var users = new List<User>()
{
    new User { Name = "Foo", SubUser = new Sub_User { Name = "Bar" } },
    new User { Name = "FooBar" }
};

users.ForEach(u => context.Users.Add(u));

context.SaveChanges();
```

If you try to add a `Sub_User` without a valid/existing `User` it fails, the following fails for example:

```
var subUsers = new List<Sub_User>()
{
    new Sub_User { Name= "Unicorn" }
};

subUsers.ForEach(su => context.SubUsers.Add(su));

context.SaveChanges();
```

**Sample Context:**

```
public class SampleContext : DbContext {

    public SampleContext() : base("SampleContext") {}

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sub_User> SubUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This seemed to Work, but I had to put the .WithRequired(su=>su.User)
I'm still not sure why this works though haha.

Comment: on second thought, this sets the primary key to the foreign key.. which is not going to work.

Comment: I see what you are saying now. I've updated my answer. You should be able to achieve the functionality you are looking for by either using `[Required]` on the `User User` with `Sub_User` or the updated Fluent API configuration. The other thing you may need to consider is `Sub_User` may need to become just `SubUser` without the underscore for convention purposes. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I marked this as the answer because your answers are awesome. But I still get the error : Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types.

When I try your option #3. I have the key and required attributes set. So not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as making Sub_User.UserID public. Otherwise, something like this might work:

```
public int UserID;

[NotMapped]
public User User
{
    get
    {
        return _context.Users.where(u=>u.UserID==UserID).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    set
    {
        UserID = value.UserID;
    }

}
```